# scalac: Error: requirement failed: package stubbing

Tags: scala, mockito, scalatest

I am using scala 2.12. This is my build.sbt file

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
   "net.codingwell" %% "scala-guice" % "4.1.0",
   "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.3" % "test",
   "org.scalamock" %% "scalamock-scalatest-support" % "3.5.0" % "test"
)
```

I am trying to write a Test Module for Guice which also uses Mocking

I Tried

```
class TestModule extends ScalaModule with MockitoSugar{
   val x = mock[TestPartialMock]
   override def configure(): Unit = {
      bind[Test1]
      bind[Test2]
   }
}
```

I got the error

```
Error:scalac: Error: requirement failed: package stubbing
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: package stubbing
    at scala.reflect.internal.Types$ModuleTypeRef.<init>(Types.scala:1879)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Types$PackageTypeRef.<init>(Types.scala:1897)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Types$TypeRef$.apply(Types.scala:2401)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Types.typeRef(Types.scala:3553)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Types.typeRef$(Types.scala:3536)
    at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.typeRef(SymbolTable.scala:16)
    at s
```

I also tried

```
class TestModule extends AbstractModule with ScalaModule with MockitoSugar {
   override def configure() = {
   }
}
```

but now I get error

```
Error:(14, 17) Symbol 'type <none>.stubbing.Answer' is missing from the classpath.
This symbol is required by 'value org.scalatest.mockito.MockitoSugar.defaultAnswer'.
Make sure that type Answer is in your classpath and check for conflicting dependencies with `-Ylog-classpath`.
A full rebuild may help if 'MockitoSugar.class' was compiled against an incompatible version of <none>.stubbing.
   override def configure() = {
```

Then I tried

```
class TestModule extends AbstractModule with ScalaModule with MockFactory with MockitoSugar {
   override def configure() = {
   }
}
```

But I get this error

```
Error:(14, 17) Symbol 'type <none>.mockito.MockSettings' is missing from the classpath.
This symbol is required by 'value org.scalatest.mockito.MockitoSugar.mockSettings'.
Make sure that type MockSettings is in your classpath and check for conflicting dependencies with `-Ylog-classpath`.
A full rebuild may help if 'MockitoSugar.class' was compiled against an incompatible version of <none>.mockito.
   override def configure() = {
```

It seems to me that its impossible to use the Guice AbstractFactory and the MockitoSugar in the same class.

Comment: Doesn't look like this is a ScalaMock question. Grateful if you could remove the tag. Also, in your self-answer below, you wouldn't need the scalamock dependency if you plan on only using Mockito :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried a little more and I resolved it. Leaving the answer here so that others can find it.

This works

SBT

```
"net.codingwell" %% "scala-guice" % "4.1.0",
"org.scalatest" % "scalatest_2.12" % "3.0.3",
"org.mockito" % "mockito-core" % "2.7.22"
```

Now define the class as

```
class TestModule extends AbstractModule with ScalaModule with MockitoSugar {
   override def configure() = {}
}
```